# Is it possible to configure AWS CodeArtifact PyPi repository to be used in AWS MWAA?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact, mwaa

[AWS MWAA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/what-is-mwaa.html) (Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow) is relatively new service provided by AWS. When configuring the MWAA environment, it is possible to provide custom `requirements.txt` file, which is used to install additional Python packages in that environment.

In the company I work for, we use [AWS CodeArtifact](https://aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/) for custom PyPi package repository, where we upload private Python packages. We want to use some of them in Airflow DAGs. That's why I was wondering if MWAA environment can be configured somehow to use the PyPi repository from CodeArtifact?

Or is there any way how to install custom Python packages (not in public PyPi) in MWAA environment?

Comment: Can you please refer to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-dependencies.html,  I see there is a section where you can add a hosted url which can be your codeartifact registry url.

Comment: Thank you. However it's not working since the only supported authentication method is Basic auth (username, password), e.g.: `--index-url=https://${AIRFLOW__FOO_USER}:${AIRFLOW__FOO_PASS}@my.privatepypi.com`. CodeArtifact uses a token as password which has to be renewed every 12 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try but should work:

```
# aws codeartifact login --tool pip --domain **--repository **
# awk '/index-url/ {print "-i "$3}' ~/.config/pip/pip.conf  > requirements.txt
# echo <my python package> >> requirements.txt
```

It can be used as normal requirements file:

```
# pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
Looking in indexes: https://aws:****
```

Please note CodeArtifact token expires maximum in 12 hours. You can create a recurring job to regenerate this file...

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Yes, this might work, but I was hoping a solution without a recurring job.

Comment: I've tried it and this works. However, if you run your MWAA Airflow Web Server in _private mode_, it won't be able to access any URLs at all it seems, even your local CodeArtifact PyPi repository URL won't work (timeouts). In public mode, it will work fine.

Comment: To add to my previous answer, I'm wondering why do we need any of the packages from `requirements.txt` on the Airflow Web Server at all? Unless we want to install any Airflow UI plugins, I don't think we need to install any additional packages on the Web Server. On the Scheduler and Workers on the other hand, we absolutely need to install those, but I doubt the Web Server needs them. So when using MWAA with the Web Server deployed in _private mode_, we could probably ignore `requirements.txt` installation errors on the Web Server itself only.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit late, AWS does provide a sample repo to fulfill your requirements. The example makes use of the AWS CDK Python to setup the VPC endpoint to Codeartifacts and your private VPC. Although the Python Lambda version is 3.7 (deprecated already), you can update it to Python 3.10 (latest) and updates the AWS CDK Python version without any issues. I recently also takes this repo and have my private MWAA made use of the codeartifact without issue. You may also update the S3 bucket and Path according to your requirement.

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-mwaa-examples/blob/main/usecases/mwaa-with-codeartifact/README.md

To install aws-cdk Nodejs

```
yarn add --global aws-cdk

npx cdk deploy CodeArtifactStack LambdaCronStack # Require LTS nodejs
```